# SP2007 > Making mysite read only

Tags: my-site

in sp 2010, it just a click to make mysite read only. The old sp2007 is slowly decommissioning and I need to make the mysite Read only. Any idea guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have users that are actively using the 2007 site that includes adding new items? Are they doing anything that involves WRITING to the database? If not, you could make the site read-only by setting the database to read-only

http://myspexp.com/2010/06/22/read-only-site/

This isn't specific to My Site of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this.. From Central Administration, using "User permissions for Web application", you can remove permissions which requires writing to database.

Comment: You are right. that's another option as well. I will just make the database read only since it's just going to be archive. Thanks for your post.